# logback cannot set timezone in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, logstash, kibana

I have an example related with **ELK** in my Spring Boot. Even if I defined timezone in **logback-spring.xml** and set my timezone in **dateFormat:tz** of **Kibana**, timestamp in document is 3 hours back of timestamp. I think timezone cannot be detected.

Here is the screenshot shown below.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxdXW.png)

Here is my project link : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootElk)

How can I fix that issue?

Here is my logback-spring.xml shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property scope="context" name="log.fileExtension" value="log"/>
    <property scope="context" name="log.fileName" value="Springboot-Elk"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,Europe/Istanbul}] [${HOSTNAME}] [%thread] %level %logger{36}@%method:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.fileName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.${log.fileExtension}</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,Europe/Istanbul}] [${HOSTNAME}] [%thread] %level %logger{36}@%method:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>logstash:5044</destination>
        <!-- encoder is required -->
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <timeZone>Europe/Istanbul</timeZone>
            <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,Europe/Istanbul</timestampPattern>
        </encoder>
        <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STASH"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STASH"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STASH"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try changing console log appender tag to

```
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{GMT+3}] [${HOSTNAME}] [%thread] %level %logger{36}@%method:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```